# gnuplot: Faulty sensor sometimes reading 0.00 - how to convert them to missing?

Tags: logging, gnuplot, sensors

I have a combination RPi/Arduino taking readings from several DHT-22 Humidity/Temperature sensors.

One of the sensors developed a loose wire and has been giving occasional 0.00 temperature readings for 10-20 minutes in a row.  Because of the other data collected at the same time I don't really have the option to just delete the whole line of data like I would if it were the only sensor being recorded.  The wire has been fixed now.

So my question is, can I do something in the gnuplot code to consider those 0.00 values as simply missing for the plot so it could ignore them?

Comment: `set datafile missing "0.00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot allows you to filter data while plotting:

```
gnuplot 'file.dat' using 1:($2 == 0.0 ? 1/0 : $2)
```

This treats all values of `0` as invalid points and those points are skipped. Depending on the selected plotting style that works, or not: `plot ... with lines` interrupts a line at an invalid point.

Since gnuplot version 5.0.6 you can use `set datafile missing NaN` to have invalid points treated as missing ones, and a line would simply ignore those points:

```
$data <<EOD
12
27
0
23
42
EOD

set multiplot layout 1,2

set title '0.0 invalid'
plot $data using 0:($1 == 0.0 ? 1/0 : $1) with linespoints pt 7 notitle

set title '0.0 invalid but treated as missing'
set datafile missing NaN
replot

unset multiplot
```

Output with 5.0.6:

[image]