# Gnuplot: how to exlude points with a condition from csplines plot

Tags: plot, conditional-statements, gnuplot

This is an example of the issue.
I want to plot the data on the first column and the csplines for them only if the second column the data is greater than 0.
So I want to exclude certain data from the interpolation.

```
0   1
1   1
3   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
4   1
2   0
5   1
7   1
9   1
3   1
2   1
1   1
0   1
```

I tried this, the usual 1/0 trick:

```
plot "data.dat" u 0:($2>0? $1:1/0) s csplines,"data.dat" u 0:1 w points
```

But the result has an ugly gap

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wszGM.png)

I tried first plotting in a table but seems that csplines can't handle the NaN.
Any suggestion?
Maybe the only solution is manipulating the file removing rows? What's the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: With version 5.0.6 you can add `set datafile missing NaN` to your script, that should simply ignore the filtered points with value `1/0`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994565/2604213

Comment: That seems pretty convenient, I'll install the latest version then. Thank you.